# Getting assertion failed error while deleting dynamic memory

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Here I am declaring a pointer's array and then calling `print()` method from class `A`

```
A *ptr1[10];

ptr1[0]= new A;

ptr1[0]->print();
```

Above works fine but when I try to delete it shows assertion failed error

```
delete[] ptr1;
```

I am using Visual studio 2010

Details of error:

[image]

Comment: 1. The assertion failure occurs _within_ the Microsoft C++ Runtime library, so it's not, specifically, you're bug, though somehow you might be triggering it.  2. Being able to see the source to the  `print` method for class `A` might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr1` is an an array of pointers to A. Since you didn't allocated ptr1 itself via `new`, then you shouldn't `delete` it.

`ptr1[0]` is a pointer to an A that you allocated. So you would just need to do `delete ptr1[0]`.

Comment: +1. Rule of thumb: if you don't use `new []`, don't use `delete []` either.

Answer (score 1):

The Good way to do:

```
#define SIZE 10

A *ptr1[SIZE];

// allocate and do print
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    ptr1[i]= new A();
    ptr1[i]->print(); 
}


// deletion
for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
{
    if(ptr1[j] != NULL)
    {
        delete ptr1[j];
        ptr1[j] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to add delete [] ptr1;
Any reason? Because you have already deleted memory by using loops.

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake.